# Is there a way to jump from a section into another section with Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two sections one over the other. 
What I want to do is that when I click the button, the first section display: none with a small transition and the second one appears. I need to do that with vanilla JavaScript as I'm learning it.

My goal is to be able to create a login when the password is entered, the person is moved to the second section. (this is just for Front end, nothing backend).

Here is the code below:

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Login Background */
#first{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #464159;
    z-index: 1;
}
    /* Login */
.login-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -100%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.logo{
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.logo img{
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
}

.user{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.w8u{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.submit{
    flex: 1;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
}

/* Menu */

 #second{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: orangered;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
        <section id="first">
            <div class="login-container">
                <!-- Logo User -->
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="w-logo.jpg" alt="User">
                </div>
                <!-- User Name -->
                <div class="user">
                    <div class="w8u">
                        <h3>User</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Submit Button -->
                <button id="btn-submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick="">GO!</button>
        </section>
    
        <section id="second">
        </section>
    
        <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Amine! Welcome to StackOverflow! When asking questions it's customary to provide the code you've tried in order to solve the issue and it looks like you're missing the JavaScript. If you could provide that, I'd be happy to help!

Comment: I didn't include the JavaScript part because I left it empty as I couldn't figure out what to write.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change CSS of elements using JavaScript:

```js
function login(){
document.getElementById("first").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("second").style.display="block";
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Login Background */
#first{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #464159;
    z-index: 1;
}
    /* Login */
.login-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -100%);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.logo{
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.logo img{
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
}

.user{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.w8u{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.submit{
    flex: 1;
    margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
}

/* Menu */

 #second{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: orangered;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    
        <section id="first">
            <div class="login-container">
                <!-- Logo User -->
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="w-logo.jpg" alt="User">
                </div>
                <!-- User Name -->
                <div class="user">
                    <div class="w8u">
                        <h3>User</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Submit Button -->
                <button id="btn-submit" class="submit" type="submit" onclick="login()">GO!</button>
        </section>
    
        <section id="second">
          Section  2
        </section>
    
        <script>

        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like it's the easiest way!

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer:

You can solve your issue by using a common pattern of **styling** transitions and **toggling classes** in JavaScript.

```js
/* Get Screen Container */
let context = document.querySelector("main.screen-container");

/* Helper Methods */ 

// Utility
const ele = context.querySelector.bind(context), 
      eles = context.querySelectorAll.bind(context);

// Action 
const showScreen = inactiveScreen => {
  const screens = eles(".screen");
  screens.forEach(screen => screen.classList.remove("active-screen"));
  inactiveScreen.classList.add("active-screen");
}

// Elements
const login_button = ele("#loginBtn"),
      logout_button = ele("#logoutBtn"),

      login_screen = ele("#login"),
      loggedIn_screen = ele("#loggedIn");


// Add Event Listeners and Handlers
login_button.addEventListener("click", () => showScreen(loggedIn_screen));
logout_button.addEventListener("click", () => showScreen(login_screen));
```

```css
.full-width-full-height {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.no-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inputs-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 200px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 5px black solid;
}

.inputs-container.inputs {
  padding: 10px;
}


.screen#login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

.screen#loggedIn {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  text-align: center;
}

highlight {
  color: rgb(0,100,0); 
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgb(0,200,0);
}

.screen-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

main section {
 position: absolute;
 height: 0px;
 width: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

main section.active-screen {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class="full-width-full-height no-overflow">
<main class="screen-container full-width-full-height">

<section id="login" class="screen active-screen">
<div class="inputs-container">
<div class="inputs"><label>Username:</label><input type="text" id="username" placeholder="admin" /></div>
<div class="inputs"><label>Password:</label><input type="password" id="password" /></div>
<button id="loginBtn">login</button>
</div>
</section>
<section id="loggedIn" class="screen">
<h3>User Successfully <highlight>Logged In</highlight></h3>
<button id="logoutBtn">logout</button>
</section>

</main>
</body>
```

---

### Explanation of Answer:

In your question you're asking for help in the following:

- Using Sections as Different Screens in an Application

  - Change Screens on an Event such as **click**
  - Transition between Screens when the Screen Changes

Something like this isn't an atypical need and, in fact, just looking at the above you can see the resemblance between what you're looking for and common things like a carousel or tab navigation.

Since this is the case there is a pretty common pattern when designing markup based around these types of requirements and this pattern is used in frameworks like BootStrap, DataTables, JQuery, etc.

---

**The Mark-Up Pattern:**

- Create a Container

  - Provide a *class* to define this type of container ( *screen-container* )
- Create Visual Elements

  - In your case Section Elements dubbed *Screens*
  - Provide a *class* to define these specific elements
  - In your case something like *screen*
  - You will likely also want to provide an ID for each of these Visual Elements based on their Content.

    - In your case something like *login* and *loggedIn*
- Create a class that will serve as the *active* Visual Element

  - In your case something like *active-screen*

Incorporating the above you end up with a basic outline:

```
<main class="screen-container">

<section id="login" class="screen active-screen"></section>
<section id="loggedIn" class="screen"></section>

</main>
```

### Example:

```css
html, body, main, .screen-container {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}


.screen-container 
  .screen {
    padding: 3px;
    background: rgba(24,24,24, .3);
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.screen-container 
  .screen.active-screen {
    border-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<main class="screen-container">

<section id="login" class="screen active-screen">login</section>
<section id="loggedIn" class="screen">logged in</section>

</main>
```

---

**Styling:**

In your initial question you say that you want to use the **display** property to hide and show your screens, **however**, you also state that you would like to have the screens *transition* from one to another.

Transitioning is definitely possible through the aptly named CSS `transition` property ( [More info on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) ).

The problem is that the **display** property is not able to be animated. If an element is configured to `display: none;` the page is **immediately** repainted with that element removed.

This means that you need to use a different property, and we typically would use `opacity` or `visibility`. Here are the differences between these three:

- `display: none;`

  - *immediately* collapses the element
  - removes the element from view.
  - There's no transition allowed.
- `visibility: hidden;`

  - Does not collapse the element

    - The space it occupied is blank.
  - removes the element from view
  - Transitions are allowed

    - The element will still *pop* out of sight.
- `opacity: 0;`

  - Does not collapse the element

    - The space it occupied is blank.
  - removes the element from view
  - Transitions are allowed.

    - The element will fade until it is not visible.

Here is an example of the different way these properties affect the layout of the page:

```js
const context = document.querySelector("#examples");

const ele = context.querySelector.bind(context),
      hide = section => section.classList.toggle("hide"),
      onClickHide = (btn, section) => btn.addEventListener("click", () => hide(section));

  opacity = ele(".opacity"),
  opacity_button = ele("#oBtn"),
  
  visibility = ele(".visibility"),
  visibility_button = ele("#vBtn"),
  
  display = ele(".display"),
  display_button = ele("#dBtn"),
  
  toggle_button = ele("#tBtn");
  

onClickHide(opacity_button, opacity);
onClickHide(visibility_button, visibility);
onClickHide(display_button, display);

toggle_button
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
  hide(opacity); 
  hide(visibility);
  hide(display);
});
```

```css
html,
body,
#examples {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#examples section {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

#examples section.hide {
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#examples section.opacity {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

#examples section.opacity.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}

#examples section.visibility {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
}

#examples section.visibility.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#examples section.display {
display: block;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

#examples section.display.hide {
color: black;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<main id="examples">
  <section class="opacity">opacity <button id="oBtn">hide</button></section>
  <hr />
  <section class="visibility">visibility <button id="vBtn">hide</button></section>
  <hr />
  <section class="display">display <button id="dBtn">hide</button></section>
  <hr/>
  <button id="tBtn">Toggle All</button>
</main>
```

**Note:** In the above there are actually two properties transitioning - `opacity`, `visibility`, or `display` - **and** `border-radius`. You should notice firstly how in the `display` example the `border-radius` change isn't seen *at all*, and secondly how the `display` example is the only one that collapses the element so that it no longer takes up space.

---

### Applying Transitions:

By combining `opacity: 0;` with `height: 0px; width: 0px;` we can remove the element visually from the page while also removing any impact it has on other elements - meaning that it **won't take up space** and **is transitionable**.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  const screens = [
    document.querySelector(".screen.active-screen"),
    document.querySelector(".screen:not(.active-screen)")
  ];
  screens[0].classList.toggle("active-screen");
  screens[0].ontransitionend = () => { 
  screens[1].classList.toggle("active-screen"); 
  screens[0].ontransitionend = undefined;
  }
}, 1000)
```

```css
html,
body,
main,
.screen-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.screen-container .screen {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}

.screen-container .screen.active-screen {
  background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .3);
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  border-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<main class="screen-container">

  <section id="login" class="screen active-screen">login</section>
  <section id="loggedIn" class="screen">logged in</section>

</main>
```

---

**JavaScript**

The final piece of the puzzle is the JavaScript mechanics of the Screens.

Any Programmer wants to make the switch as easy as possible, and this is done typically by providing a function that allows for quick reassignment of the class `active-screen` by removing it from the current active screen and applying it to the desired visual element.

One thing to take into account is that you want your queries for elements to be **as specific** as possible. Meaning that instead of `document.querySelector` you want to provide the smallest **context** of where to find your Visual Elements. a.e.

```
/* Get Screen Container */
let context = document.querySelector("main.screen-container");

/* Helper Methods */ 

// Utility
const ele = context.querySelector.bind(context), 
      eles = context.querySelectorAll.bind(context);
```

This prevents **code collision** where other code in your Application's JavaScript, Styling, or Mark-Up may utilize a `screen` or `active-screen` class that isn't relevant to what you're doing here.

**Note:** This is actually a problem in BootStrap currently. It searches for the `active` class in it's Tab architecture. This is such a generic class name that other libraries utilize it and it can cause a giant headache to get things to work properly. Writing explicit patching because you didn't think through your design fully is something I'd just as soon spare you from, so *try* to keep interactivity with other code in mind.

---

Lastly we write our function ( `showScreen` ) that allow for quick, easy switching between screens:

```
// Action 
const showScreen = inactiveScreen => {
  const screens = eles(".screen");
  screens.forEach(screen => screen.classList.remove("active-screen"));
  inactiveScreen.classList.add("active-screen");
}
```

**And believe it or not, that's pretty much it!**

All that's left to do is apply this functionality to your `button` **click** events and it works just as it should:

---

### Result:

```js
/* Get Screen Container */
let context = document.querySelector("main.screen-container");

/* Helper Methods */ 

// Utility
const ele = context.querySelector.bind(context), 
      eles = context.querySelectorAll.bind(context);

// Action 
const showScreen = inactiveScreen => {
  const screens = eles(".screen");
  screens.forEach(screen => screen.classList.remove("active-screen"));
  inactiveScreen.classList.add("active-screen");
}

// Elements
const login_button = ele("#loginBtn"),
      logout_button = ele("#logoutBtn"),

      login_screen = ele("#login"),
      loggedIn_screen = ele("#loggedIn");


// Add Event Listeners and Handlers
login_button.addEventListener("click", () => showScreen(loggedIn_screen));
logout_button.addEventListener("click", () => showScreen(login_screen));
```

```css
.full-width-full-height {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.no-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inputs-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 height: 200px;
 padding: 5px;
 border: 5px black solid;
}

.inputs-container.inputs {
  padding: 10px;
}


.screen#login {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

}

.screen#loggedIn {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  text-align: center;
}

highlight {
  color: rgb(0,100,0); 
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgb(0,200,0);
}

.screen-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

main section {
 position: absolute;
 height: 0px;
 width: 0px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

main section.active-screen {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<body class="full-width-full-height no-overflow">
<main class="screen-container full-width-full-height">

<section id="login" class="screen active-screen">
<div class="inputs-container">
<div class="inputs"><label>Username:</label><input type="text" id="username" placeholder="admin" /></div>
<div class="inputs"><label>Password:</label><input type="password" id="password" /></div>
<button id="loginBtn">login</button>
</div>
</section>
<section id="loggedIn" class="screen">
<h3>User Successfully <highlight>Logged In</highlight></h3>
<button id="logoutBtn">logout</button>
</section>

</main>
</body>
```

---

### Conclusion:

I hope this helps and gives you some insight into how this pattern is used! It's not a difficult thing to learn, but it's incredibly useful!

**Good luck and Happy Coding!**

Comment: I appreciate every word you have put in this answer! I have learnt a lot, and I'm definitely putting into work what you have explained!

Comment: @AmineBelmahi sure thing! If you liked mine and the other answer, be sure to upvote or accept as your answer for the question. There's an arrow and a checkmark next to each question :)